# need to change the adapter data and show in gridviwer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am able to get some data on the adapter and show in the grid view.it gives some Category, Subcategory, price using Id, therefore, some Category, Subcategory, price are same and then it will repeat. Now I want to introduce a quantity column and update this number.how can I do that

```
SqlDataAdapter cda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Category,Subcategory ,Price from Main m left outer join Subcategory s on m.SubcategoryID= s.[S.ID] join Category c on m.CategoryID= c.[C.ID] WHERE Status = 'ACTIVE' AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE m.EPC = table3.EPC)", con);
DataTable cdt = new DataTable();
cda.Fill(cdt); BindingSource cbs = new BindingSource();
cbs.DataSource = cdt; 
dataGridView2.DataSource = cbs; 
cda.Update(cdt);
```

Comment: Please [edit] new info directly into the question.

Comment: looks like You are using some code without understanding it. "Now I want to introduce a quantity column" You need to add new column in Your table, and add column name to select statement, later on do research about SQL Update command